# How to register a user with orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

So in the User.cshtml file in the bootstrap theme I am setting up 'Register' to navigate to the CheckoutController/Signup() with

```
 @Html.ActionLink(T("Register").Text, "Signup", new { Controller = "Checkout", Area = "UMACS.FoodPod", ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })
```

which attempts to create a shape with _services (which is private readonly IOrchardServices _services;)

```
 [Themed]
    public ActionResult Signup()
    {
        var shape = _services.New.Checkout_Signup();
        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
    }
```

However it throws an error when trying to create this:

```
Exception Details: Orchard.OrchardException: Shape type Checkout_Signup not found
```

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what this shape thing is trying to do. I've used this code (which iv just copied over atm) before to create a registration login. which has worked fine in the past and dont know why this error is throwing now...any ideas? on how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orchard is looking for the Checkout_Signup shape, which means it is looking for a view called Checkout.Signup.cshtml. So I assume that you have not created this file.

For example, In the LogOn function of the Orchard.Users.Controllers.AccountController, it performs the same function `var shape = _orchardServices.New.LogOn()` which uses Orchard.Users.Views.LogOn.cshtml to build the shape. Then  it passes this shape to the ShapeResult(). Which then renders the LogOn.cshtml.

So in your module, create a Checkout.Signup.cshtml file in your Views folder.

As to why Checkout_Signup maps to Checkout.Signup.cshtml, please see http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Comment: ahh yes thanks for the reply. Problem is in my previous project I had the Checkout.Signup.cshtml inside my view folded. This time I was attempting to put a Signup.cshtml file inside a checkout folder in the 'view' folder